# Getting exception org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException:

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am using Cucumber and Java to automate Selenium test cases. Using Jenkins to execute the job. The job is scheduled to run every day. However, after a few test case runs, my task failed with the following error, which is an intermittent problem. Is there anything that can be done in this scenario?

**Error**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:29896 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'QTSAUTOMATION', ip: '10.2.0.166', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_241' 
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver    at com.TestAutomation.TestRunner.TestRunner.runScenario(TestRunner.java:38) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Are using any kind of VPN?

Comment: No, it's on a server, and there's no VPN.

Comment: I believe you are RemoteWebDriver. Is that correct? If yes, then in this case it can happen. Your machine and server connected to different networks.

Comment: Exactly, that is the case. could you please suggest on what can be done in this case? is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836113/can-different-network-be-the-cause-for-unreachablebrowserexception-exception

Comment: No problem. Thank you for showing me the right direction for resolving the issue.