# UnreachableBrowserException while running selenium scripts inside the agent

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, agent

Getting UnreachableBrowserException while running selenium scripts with docker configured in the CI pipeline, This issue only occurs while executing all the cases together in the agent , it works fine locally.

Comment: Its seems like similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836113/can-different-network-be-the-cause-for-unreachablebrowserexception-exception

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.